# TimeDate method check returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to return true/false from a rails method, but it keeps returning nil.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
def method_name?
  DateTime.now < DateTime.new(2018, 5, 14, 23, 59, 59)
end
```

I'm then calling it via

```
<% if @method_name %>

  Show this

<% else %>

  Show that

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume `method_name?` is in helper. Please change:

```
<% if @method_name %>
```

to

```
<% if method_name? %>
```

Call `@method_name` means access instance variable which doesn't exist so that it return `nil`.